# What is the difference between using () or {} after the arrow in an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, arrow-functions

I usually always write an arrow function and when I need it to be multi-lined then I do "{}". However, I am watching a tutorial, and in it, he is writing this useEffect function:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chatId) {
      db.collection("chats")
        .doc(chatId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({
            id:doc.id,
            data:doc.data()
          })))
        ));
    }
  }, []);
```

notice after "snapshot" he has "=> (" not "=> {" and also snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({ where there is a "({" rather than just a "{". Someone help me understand what I am missing here?

Comment: When your arrow function returns an object literal you need to wrap it in parenthesis so the transpiler can distinguish it from a function.

Comment: Explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is generally the best place to start

Answer (score 1):

Each use of parenthesis and curly brackets has a different result based on the purpose. Using curly brackets by themselves will not return a result, which may be desired or you can use `return` to return a result.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // If I want to return a result, I need to use the return keyword
})
```

If you want to return a result immediately from the function, you can either place the returned result immediately after the `=>` or wrap it in parenthesis.

```js
// These are equivalent
snapshot => setMessages()
snapshot => (setMessages())
```

Finally, if you want to return an object from the function, you wrap the curly brackets with parenthesis. This indicates that you want to return a value rather than returning nothing like the first example.

```js
doc => ({
  id:doc.id,
  data:doc.data()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run multiple commands inside callback function, you need to use {}.

Actually, `snapshot => (setMessages(...))` is equivalent with `snapshot => {return setMessages(...)}`

Answer (score 0):

- Traditional Function

```
function (a) {
    return a + 100;
}
```

- Remove the word "function" and place arrow between the argument and opening body bracket

```
(a) => {
    return a + 100;
}
```

- Remove the body brackets and word "return" -- the return is implied.

```
(a) => a + 100;
```

- Remove the argument parentheses

```
a => a + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The grammar of an arrow functions allow for either a block `{ }` or an expression. Since an object literal (an expression) is also `{ }` there is an ambiguity between a block an object literal. So the standard dictates that `{ }` is always a block in this scenario.

Using `({ })` allows you to wrap the object literal expression with a parenthesis expression which just evaluates to the object literal. In other words, a handy way to bypass the ambiguity restriction.

Of course, the reason that it allows a block (`{ }`) in the first place is to offer different semantics to its expression counterpart. A block would mean that you are writing a function body, e.g. multiple statements is possible as is using a `return` statement. Its expression counterpart just allows for one expression.